# Scala - printing specific fields in each line from a file

Tags: scala

While learning, I'm trying to read a web log and extract few fields from it. The web log will be like below

```
147.172.225.10 - 16401 [16/Sep/2013:23:52:35 +0100] "GET /KBDOC-00057.html HTTP/1.0" 200 11761 "http://www.newbie.com"  "test F20L"
147.172.225.10 - 16401 [16/Sep/2013:23:52:35 +0100] "GET /theme.css HTTP/1.0" 200 12353 "http://www.newbie.com"  "test Mobile Browser Sorrento F20L"
23.53.29.101 - 32693 [16/Sep/2013:23:49:50 +0100] "GET /KBDOC-00035.html HTTP/1.0" 200 9337 "http://www.newbie.com"  "test Mobile Browser i3"
```

And I need to extract just the IP address and User id(3rd field) from the logs and print as

```
147.172.225.10/16401
147.172.225.10/16401
23.53.29.101/32693
```

If I have to use map or flatMap, could someone help me how and let me know if there is a better way to accomplish it. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I used below to get the required results.

```
map(line => line.split(' ')).map(fields => (fields(0) + "/" + fields(2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For each line(as string) in the weblog, you can use split method on the basis of a blank character, and after splitting it will return an array of string, with that, you can extract the required values.

```
lines map { line =>
  val lineArray = line.split(" ")
  lineArray(0), lineArray(2)
}
```